# Using MYSQL's MD5() operation in a SELECT DISTINCT statement ignores the DISTINCT clause

Tags: mysql, md5, distinct

So if I do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_1, column_2, MD5(rand()) 
FROM table
```

I get n number of rows which is the correct number of distinct rows.

And if I do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_1, column_2, "whatever"
FROM table
```

the above returns n+m which is basically all the rows from table.

What is happening here?

Comment: so you're now doing a `select blah from table group by column_1, column_2` right?  or do you need an answer with that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A break down of your queries:

SELECT DISTINCT column_1, column_2 FROM table

will return the distinct results for column_1 AND column_2 . For example if you have:

```
column_1 column_2
Peter 26 
John 27
Adam 26
Fred 25
```

the result will be all four rows.

Including MD5(rand()) will generate a new column and will thus return all results from the table (counter to what you actually report - the number of distinct rows). i.e. SELECT DISTINCT column_2, MD5(rand()) FROM table will also return 4 rows:

```
26, 2c346f92e3ccccfeccc75b1f8fbec910
27, 6f8af159c2658cf8a33d0e29419a71a6
26, 4f7f54cd9527c509da322caeb31c73c9
25, 01a4a55f61cba7ef922180b5520698d2
```

On the other hand - passing the same value to the query will actually return a distinct number of results.i.e. SELECT DISTINCT column_2, "whatever" FROM table will return 3 rows:

```
26, whatever
27, whatever
25, whatever
```